# Using CPLEX academic version with Pyomo on MacOS

Tags: python, pyomo, cplex-python-api

I have recently tried to use the CPLEX solver to solve one of my Pyomo models. I first installed the community version that is available:https://pypi.org/project/cplex/ using `pip`.

However, I am trying to switch to the academic license of the solver and I am facing several problems.
The main issue is that when I call `SolverFactory('cplex')` I get the following error:

> pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'cplex'

If I use "cplex_direct" the solver works as expected but the community edition is used instead. I also tried running the `setup.py` script available at `/Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/python/3.9/x86-64_osx` but I could not fix the problem. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

One of the following will probably solve the problem:

1. Add Cplex to the system Path in your laptop
2. add `executable=` to the Solver factory:

   solver = SolverFactory(cplex, executable='C:/Program Files/...')

Comment: Doesn't your answer refers to Windows specifically? I tried a similar approach on MacOS but it did not work. Can you elaborate more if you are familiar with how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

To run CPLEX on MacOS use the code:

```
    solver = SolverFactory('cplex', executable = '/Applications/CPLEX_Studio2211/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx/cplex')
```